# Importing to SQL Mysql instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm importing data from Storage to SQL GCP (MySql datacloud). When I select the .sql file and the database there is an error message: Sorry, there’s a problem. If you entered information, check it and try again. Otherwise, the problem might clear up on its own, so check back later.

I'm trying using only one catalog table and I have the same mistake. Could you help me? please

Comment: If you could describe the procedure being used, with any applicable references, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the database before?
It seems that the problem might be with the sql file, that file is a sql dump?

The normal process for migrating to CloudSQL would be:

- Create the instance, if your source will be (MySQL) you need to select MySQL.
- Create database
- Select the database, IMPORT
- Select from sql file, and select the file

You need to have permissions for creating an instance and database.

Comment: I run using SSH in GCP and this file run correctly. But if I try to run using the import screen from GCP it doen't work

Comment: SSH? Using Cloud Shell? The instance is a CloudSQL instance? or an Compute Engine Instance with MySQL?  Can you give more details from the Error msg?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to input correct parameters like (correct GCS path, valid file, correct database name and table)? Please note that for compressed (.gz file) and sql (dump) file, SQL format should be selected instead of CSV.